# Перевести строку с unicode символами в нормальный вид

Tags: c#

Собственно есть строка вида `me":"Playboy\u2122","g` её нужно привести в нормальный вид заменив юникод \u2122 на соответствующий символ ™

Comment: как вы пркдставляете себе результат? Чтобы отладчик студии вам показывал юникод в том виде, что вы хотите?

Comment: мне нужно вывести в texbox результат и сохранить в файл

Comment: Попробуйте `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(@"Playboy\u2122");`

Comment: мне нужно все юникод символы перевести в нормальный вид, это строка для примера

Comment: @Monolith в вашем случае анэскейпом должен заниматься десериализатор json. Не разбирайте строку вручную, скормите ее какому-нибудь json.net - и получите нормальный объект с нормальными значениями внутри.

Answer (score 1):

Все спокойно выводится, вот код (сделал шрифт побольше, чтобы было видно на картинке)

```
class F : Form
{
    public F()
    {
        var tb = new TextBox();

        Font fnt=new Font(tb.Font.FontFamily,14.0F);
        tb.Font = fnt;

        tb.Text = "Playboy\u2122";      
        this.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
}
```

Результат. Никаких проблем.

[image: пример]

Comment: ну это если явно задать в коде, а если у меня строка формируется данными ответа на гет запрос?

Comment: @Monolith не вижу у вас в вопросе что либо про гет запрос. Вы привели пример строки - я показал, как её использовать. Откуда мне знать, что у вас за запрос, что за ответ и какая кодировка строк в том вашем ответе, который вы не упомянули в вопросе? :)

Comment: получается \u2122 в отладчике выглядит \\u2122 а не \u2122, как избежать комментирования?

Comment: @tym32167 Что же Вы не догадались, что `me":"Playboy\u2122",` в вопросе - это обломок JSON-a?

Comment: @Igor у меня нет гномиков, которые могли бы подсказать :)

Comment: @tym32167 Ваши гномики уехали в отпуск?

Comment: @Monolith не смотрите что в отладчике, смотрите заголовки http ответа, какая там кодировка? Вы строку оттуда пробовали вывести в текстбокс?

Comment: @Igor у них тикет с race condition, они в шоке )

Comment: me":"Playboy\u2122","g в отете так вот, вот ссылка https://playfortuna.com/en/winners

Comment: @Monolith , у меня нет возможности это исследовать за вас (даже если бы хотел - ссылка ваша для меня забанена фаерволом), вам придется это делать самому. А если вы эту информацию (о том что за строка. откуда строка, в какой кодировке строка) укажете в вопросе, вероятно, кто то ещё сможет это прочитать и вам помочь

Comment: @Monolith и в следующий раз. пожалуйста, пишите все детали сразу в вопросе, а то сейчас получилось, что я потратил свое время на код, который бесполезен и вам и мне просто потому что вы в вопросе указали не все, что относится к вопросу.